# Split up Google Anlytics Dimensions after sorting?

Tags: android, ios, sorting, google-analytics, analytics

I am querying Google Analytics (app) data and I want the TOP 10 `ga:screenName` and then split them up by `ga:operatingSystem`. If I just query for `dimensions=ga:operatingSystem,ga:screenName` and `metrics=ga:screenViews`, `sort=-ga:screenviews`, `max-results=20` I get mostly Android results (17/20) since Android makes up more of the traffic than iOS does.

Is there a way to apply the sort first on the TOP 10 screens and then split it up between android and iOS? Right now I am doing pivot table sort on total and then taking the top 20 fields. It isn't super smooth and I was wondering if I could filter right at the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could break it out into two queries one for Top 10 screens for Anroid and one for Top 10 screens for iOS.

Just add `filters==ga:operatingSystem==iOS`to the first query and `filters==ga:operatingSystem==Android` to the second query.

Comment: I know I could use two queries. The question was, for performance purposes to do it in one.